# Avg Value of Dependent Events

Tags: combinatorics, markov-chains

If I have 26 bins and on a given "turn" each bin can take on one of many values, or no value at all (null) with probability that varies by bin. Let's call the average of the values that can occur A-Z, and the probability that a non-null value occurs for a given bin a-z. You start with 5 turns, and in the event none of the bins get a value on a given turn, you lose a turn. If you do get one or more values on a given turn, the values stay there until you are out of turns, the number of turns is reset to 5.

Is there a simplish way to calculate the average value for this series of events using some clever combinatorics? Even though each bin outcome is independent I called the events dependent, because the number of turns depends on getting or not getting a value in the other bins. Please let me know if I can clarify anything, I know it sounds strange.

Comment: Anybody have a clue as to if this doesn't have a simple combinatorics solution, or if Markov chain is my only option? Maybe I could explain this better as a binary sequence? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you keep filling bins until you have five turns in a row that no new bin gets filled?  That seems to be the effect of resetting the turns counter after you fill a bin.  I doubt you can say anything very clever with the chance of filling each bin different.

Comment: The chances of you losing a turn are $p$. Then you can calculate the average number of turns played. For each turn, you know average value for each bin. Multiply the two.

Comment: Hey Ross, yes that is correct. If the probabilities were the same of getting a non-null value, would it be easier. Your chance of losing a turn late in the "event" is then (1-p)^(available spaces left), where p is the probability of a non-null value, but that varies as you go.

Comment: So the turn is lost only if no NEW bins are filled? What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Yes, a turn is lost when you get no new bins, and if you do add one or more bins on a given turn, your turns left reset to 5. The average value of the full event. The full event being the start until you run out of turns, or all bins are not null.

Comment: What are probabilities of getting a null-value in the bin on a given turn? Small? Large?

Comment: Varies by bin, but definitely between 10% and 90%.

Answer (score 1):

For $i\in[1,n]$ ($n=26$) you have geometrically distributed variables $G_i\sim Geom(p_i)$ that describe the time of the first fill of that bucket. Let $G_{(i)}$ be their order statistics with $G_{(0)}=0$ and $G_{(n+1)}=\infty$. Then the process ends at time $T=\min\{s:\exists i\in[0,n]:G_{(i)}+k\le s<G_{(i+1)}\}$ and you only need $E(T)$.

I don't know how to solve this version, but you can Poissonize and instead imagine a non-homogeneous Poisson process of "new fill in bucket $i$ "with $\lambda_i(t)=\lambda_ie^{-\lambda_i t}$ for $\lambda_i=-\log(1-p_i)$ for a total rate of "new fills" of $g(t)=\sum_i^n\lambda_i(t)$. Then for $t>k$, $$-\bar F'_{T}(t)=\bar F_T(t-k)g(t-k)\exp(-\int_{t-k}^{t}g(x)\,dx)$$ and $\bar F_T(t)=1$ for $t\le k$ which you could integrate in the piece-wise fashion. Adding $\frac 1 2$ (or $\log 2$) to $T$ would address discretization issues but I have no idea how good of approximation this would be (not that the delayed equation is that tractable analytically either).